# Uploading of a CSV to BigQuery fails

Tags: google-bigquery

I have using the bigquery uploading system over 3 months , I push data to bigquery for every one hour and it has been working fine . But since yesterday , all my Uploads are failing . Error at the bigquery console says " Too few columns: expected 11 column(s) but got 9 column(s)" , The ninth field has a new line character and  it is inside double quotes . This has been working for the past 3 months and It is failing from yesterday . Any help guys ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday we started enforcing not allowing quoted newlines unless the `allowQuotedNewlines` flag is passed.
If you are using the bq tool, you can add the --allow_quoted_newlines flag. If you are using java, you can set this [here](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobConfigurationLoad.html#setAllowQuotedNewlines%28java.lang.Boolean%29). The flag is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs).

Disallowing quoted newlines by default allows us to import csv files much more efficiently because we can split them into pieces and import in parallel. This translates into faster imports and allows us to scale to much larger imports.

Comment: Thanks jordan for the quick response , The system started to working without any change from yesterday night , So should I Add the flag or leave the code as it is ?

Comment: We flipped the default back temporarily in order to give people more time to set the flag if needed. So yes, you should set the flag because we'll likely turn the default back to requiring it early next week.